# Python one-liner if else statement

Tags: python

This problem is taken from codingbat. Given two int values, return their sum. Unless the two values are the same, then return double their sum.

I'm trying to solve it in one line:

```
def sum_double(a, b):
    return 2*(a+b) if (a == b) else return a+b
```

But I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not an if/else *statement* on a single line; it's a conditional *expression*, selecting one of two values, not one of two return statements.

Comment: omit the second `return`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have a return in the else clause. It should be:

```
def sum_double(a, b):
  return 2*(a+b) if (a == b) else a+b
```

Answer (score 7):

You have 2 options:

1. Use the `if/else` statement:

   ```
   def sum_double(a, b):
       if (a == b):                                 #if/else statement
           return 2*(a+b) # <--- return statement   #^
       else:                                        #^
           return a+b     # <--- return statement   #^
   ```
2. Use the `if/else` conditional expression:

   ```
   def sum_double(a, b):
       return 2*(a+b) if (a == b) else a+b
   #         (^                          ^)  <--- conditional expression 
   #  (^                                 ^)  <--- return statement
   ```

each has different syntax and meaning

Answer (score 4):

You should delete the second `return`.

```
def sum_double(a, b):
    return 2*(a+b) if a == b else a+b
```

The value of the `2*(a+b) if a == b else a+b` expression is what you actually want to return.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, True, False are the same as 1, 0:

```
def sum_double(a, b): return ((a==b) + 1) * (a+b)
```

Or using lambda,

```
sum_double = lambda a, b: ((a==b) + 1) * (a+b)
```