# Python oneliner with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am wondering if it is possible to write the following python if statement in one line. I would also like to know why I am getting the error below:

```
python -c 'a=1; if True: print a; else: a=a+1'

  File "<string>", line 1
    a=1; if True: print a; else: a=a+1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You didn't include the error message, but it's probably a `SyntaxError`.  And no, you can't put all that on a single line.  You can write code with the same meaning on a single line, but not using the same control structures.  And why would you want to?

Comment: exec ('a = 1\nif True:\n\tprint a\nelse:\n\t a+=1')   ;=) (please note the smiley)

Comment: Code with the same meaning on a single line would be `print 1`.

Comment: Some good answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883470/python-one-liner-if-else-statement

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right, sorry I forgot but added it to my question, now. Some people want oneliners in their shell scripts.

Comment: @FrankBreitling Those people are wrong.  Code should be clear in the first place.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's your personal opinion but some people might prefer a oneliner for clarity.

Comment: @FrankBreitling Of course, if you need something simple that can be clearly expressed in a single line, go for it by all means.  But trying to cramp more code in a single line never increases clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only [simple statements can appear in a semicolon-separate statement list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-stmt_list):

```
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

An `if` statement is a compound statement, so it's invalid syntax to include it.

Allowing compound statements in a semicolon-separated list would lead to ambiguity.  This is valid syntax:

```
if condition: a = 1; b = 1
```

Both assignments are only executed if the `condition` is true, and this is how most people would intuitively read the statement.  If we allowed

```
c = 1; if condition: a = 1; b = 1
```

it would become unclear for readers of the code whether the `b = 1` is part of the `if` statement or not.

Python uses indentation to delimit code suites, and you can't use indentation in a semicolon-separated statement list.

Comment: It's not just the indentation, this is also invalid: `a=1;print(a) if True else a=a+1`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: This is invalid for completely unrelated reasons.  The confitional expression `x if condition else y` is an expression, and `x` and `y` must be expressions, too.  An assignment isn't an expression in Python (and it Python 2, neither is `print(a)`).